# How do I convert a decimal fraction to binary in Java?

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I need to convert 0.5 in base 10 to base 2 (0.1). 
I have tried using

```
Double.doubleToRawLongBits(0.5)
```

and it returns `4602678819172646912` which I guess is in hex, but it does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply you number by 2^n, convert to an BigInteger, convert to *binary* String, add a decimal point at position n (from right to left).

Example (quick & ++dirty):

```
private static String convert(double number) {
    int n = 10;  // constant?
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number);
    BigDecimal mult = new BigDecimal(2).pow(n);
    bd = bd.multiply(mult);
    BigInteger bi = bd.toBigInteger();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(bi.toString(2));
    while (str.length() < n+1) {  // +1 for leading zero
        str.insert(0, "0");
    }
    str.insert(str.length()-n, ".");
    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why we took n=10 here?

Comment: "quick & DIRTY" that is the number of digits after the decimal point - arbitrarily chosen... (could have been an method argument)

Comment: can you please do this using recursion. @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: @AshishKumarPal the only loop is for adding "0"; why should that be done with recursion?

Answer (score 6):

No. 4602678819172646912 is in dec, hex is 0x3fe0000000000000. To dismantle that:

```
   3   |   F   |   E   |  0 ...
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
s|  exponent         |  mantissa
```

s is the sign bit, exponent is the exponent shifted by 2^9 (hence this exponent means -1), mantissa is the xxx part of the number 1.xxx (1. is implied). Therefore, this number is 1.000...*2^-1, which is 0.5.

Note that this describes the "normal" numbers only, so no zeros, denormals, NaNs or infinities

Comment: Can you please give me code that takes 0.5 in base 10 and gives me "0.1" (base 2)

Answer (score 1):

This is decimal for `0x3FE0_0000_0000_0000`. The mantissa is the list of zeros after 3FE (which codes sign and exponent). This is what you are looking for, given that 0.1 before the zeros is implicit.

Comment: Ok, how to i convert 0x3FE0_0000_0000_0000 to the string "0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to convert the decimal string to floating-point binary or to a binary string? If the former, just use valueOf(); if the latter, use valueOf() followed by toString() or printf().

Answer (score -2):

0.1 is NOT a binary representation of 0.5

Java will represent 0.5 using IEEE 754, as specified on the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#9208). `BigInteger.valueOf(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(0.5)).toByteArray()` will give you a byte per byte representation of 0.5 as Java does internally.

Comment: "0.1 is NOT a binary representation of 0.5" -- Well, it is, but it's not the IEEE 754 representation. Those are not the same thing.