# converting decimal fraction to binary fraction in Scala

Tags: scala, floating-point

I have a sequence of decimal numbers between 1 and 2. After taking their reciprocal, I want the number converted in binary form so that I can isolate the 10 MSBs of the reciprocal. 
I don't want to convert it in IEEE-754 floating point representation, but simply in binary format.

```
reciprocal = 1.0/3.0
Double = 0.3333333333333333
```

The above number on manually converting to binary will give me an infinite bit stream:

```
reciprocalBits = 0.0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101...
```

I want the 10 most-significant bits of the above binary number.
How do I convert `reciprocal` to `reciprocalBits` in Scala.

Comment: The Java code at http://stackoverflow.com/a/756715/86485 might be useful here, but maybe somebody knows something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val reciprocal = 1.0/3.0
reciprocal: Double = 0.3333333333333333

scala> List.tabulate(10)(x => ((reciprocal * math.pow(2,x)).toInt % 2))
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```